# How to read whatsapp message from notification extras

Tags: android, mobile, bitmap, notifications, whatsapp

Hi I'm working on an app in which I have to read images from whatsapp. I can read the first image as a bitmap with this line of code:

```
Bitmap btm = (Bitmap) sbn.getNotification().extras.get(Notification.EXTRA_PICTURE);
```

The problem is that if I receive more than one images I get null. How can I resolve this?

Comment: How are the images passed in the whatsapp application ? How do you extract images from another app ? Posting 2 lines of code is no help for anyone

Comment: hi i need just to read the pictures!! you will find the code of notification listner below !

Answer (score 1):

this is the `NotificationListenerService`:

```
package com.etaure.callany.testwhatsappimage;

import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService;
import android.service.notification.StatusBarNotification;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONArray;

/**
 * Created by administrator on 03/11/2015.
 */
public class MyNotificationListner extends NotificationListenerService {

    static int i = 0;

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {

        if (sbn.getPackageName().equals("com.whatsapp")) {

            Bitmap btm = (Bitmap) sbn.getNotification().extras.get(Notification.EXTRA_PICTURE);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        Log.w("Test", "NotificationRemoved");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a code that parses for you whatsapp images and shows ( if you want ) on your logcat all base64 string! Enjoy

`

```
           if (extras.containsKey(Notification.EXTRA_PICTURE)) {
            bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get(Notification.EXTRA_PICTURE);
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
            byteArrayS = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();
            encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayS, Base64.DEFAULT);

            final int LOGCAT_MAX_LENGTH = 3950;
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                while (encoded.length() > LOGCAT_MAX_LENGTH) {
                    int substringIndex = encoded.lastIndexOf(",", LOGCAT_MAX_LENGTH);
                    if (substringIndex == -1)
                        substringIndex = LOGCAT_MAX_LENGTH;
                    Log.d("encode", encoded.substring(0, substringIndex));
                    encoded = encoded.substring(substringIndex).trim();
                }
                Log.d("encode", encoded);
            }

        }
```

`